# Dificuldades com responsividade

Tags: css

To tendo dificuldades com responsividade, eu quero saber porque eu não to conseguindo adaptar meu site pra essa resolução de 720x1280, teoricamente meu site deveria se encaixar bem em modo paisagem nesses celulares pois eu fiz ele em 1000px, e nessa outra resolução de 720 eu já fiz a responsividade usando a media query "@media screen and (max-width: 720px)", mas não tá dando certo. Já fiz a responsividade pra 480px também e nada do layout se encaixar em 720px. O que tá acontecendo?

Obs: eu não usei mobile first, eu sei que é melhor.

Como eu to fazendo isso pela primeira vez talvez eu esteja fazendo alguma besteira, eu vou explicar pra vocês como eu estou fazendo a responsividade, eu to começando em 854px e to indo até 320px, to fazendo uma media query embaixo da outra:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 854px)
{
    css...
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px)
{
css...
}
@media screen and (max-width: 720px)
{
    css...
}

...

@media screen and (max-width: 320px)
{
    css...
}
```

Eu to fazendo assim meio por intuição mesmo pois no computador, redimensionando o navegador, tá tudo funcionando, no entanto nos celulares não.

Edição: Acrescentando os códigos.

style.css (css principal)

```css
body
{
 background:#356033;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}
.container
{
 width:1000px;
 padding:0;
 margin:auto;
}

/* CABEÇALHO */

header #logo
{
 margin: 34px 27px 35px 27px;
 float:left;
}
header #livros
{
 float:left;
 margin-top:20px;
}
header #pesquisar
{
 width:268px;
 height:27px;
 border-radius:5px;
 font:22px Trebuchet;
 border:none;
 margin:10px 0 0 10px;
}
header #lupa
{
 margin:8px 0 0 10px;
 float:left;
}
header .menu_nav
{
 background:#B35900;
 width:47px;
 height:47px;
 border-radius:7px;
 float:right;
 border:1px solid #FFFFFF;
 margin-top:35px;
 padding:0 0 8px 4.5px;
 display:none;
}
header .grade
{
 height:4px;
 width:36px;
 margin-top:8px;
 background:#FFFFFF;
}
header .pesquisa
{
 background: linear-gradient(#B7620D, #B35900);
 width:338px;
 height:47px;
 border:1px solid #FFFFFF;
 border-radius:7px;
 margin:35px 8px;
 float:right;
}
.clear
{
 clear:both;
}
header nav
{
 background: linear-gradient(#B7620D, #B35900);
 width:984px;
 height:57px;
 border-radius:7px;
 margin-left:8px;
}
header nav ul li
{
 float:left;
 font:28px Trajan Pro;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 padding:13px 34px 7px 30px;
 border-radius:7px;
 border-bottom:none;
}
header #final_list
{
 width:211px;
}
header nav ul
{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 list-style:none;
}
header .divisor
{
 width:3px;
 height:31px;
 background:#FFFFFF;
 float:left;
 margin-top:12px;
}
header a
{
 float:left;
 color:#FFFFFF;
}
header a:hover
{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#FFFFFF;
}
header ul li:hover
{
 background: linear-gradient(#CD6C0C, #B6610B);
}

/* PÁGINA HOME */

.categorias
{
 background: linear-gradient(#B7620D, #B35900);
 width:248px;
 border-radius:7px;
 margin:30px 15px 8px 8px;
 padding-bottom:15px;
 float:left;
}
.categorias h1
{
 border-bottom:3px solid #FFFFFF;
 font:28px Trajan Pro;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 margin:10px 0 0 10px;
 width:227px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}
.categorias a
{
 display:inline-block;
 border-bottom:1px dotted #FFFFFF;
 width:218px;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 padding-top:20px;
}
.categorias a:hover
{
 background: linear-gradient(#CD6C0C, #B6610B);
}
.categorias nav
{
 float:left;
}
.categorias ul
{
 list-style:none;
 padding:0;
}
.categorias ul li
{
 font:25px Trajan Pro;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 width:238px;
 margin-left:10px;
}
#page_livros .categorias
{
 margin-bottom:15px;
}
.banner_desenhos
{
 width:716px;
 background:#FFFFFF;
 float:right;
 margin-top:30px;
 margin-right:8px;
 padding:30px 0 0 30px;
 text-align:center;
}
.banner_desenhos span
{
 cursor:pointer;
 font-size:50px;
 color:#CCC;
 float:left;
 margin-right:6px;
}
.banner_desenhos span.cycle-pager-active
{ 
 color: #D69746;
}
.banner_desenhos .exemple-pager
{
 text-align:center;
}
#baquetas
{
 float:left;
 margin:35px 5px 10px 0;
}
.baquetas_livros
{
 clear:both;
}
.livros
{
 width:716px;
 height:1130px;
 background:#FFFFFF;
 float:right;
 margin:-10px 8px 8px 0;
 padding-bottom:20px;
 font:20px Trebuchet MS;
 text-align:center;
 position:relative;
}
.livros figcaption
{
 width:132px;
 height:50px;
}
.livros h1
{
 padding:23px 35px 23px 35px;
 background:#356033;
 margin:10px 0 10px 36px;
 width:638px;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 font:30px Trajan Pro;
}
.livros h2
{
 text-align:center;
}
.livros h2
{
 text-align:center;
}
.livros #grade_livros
{
 width:638px;
 height:6px;
 background:#356033;
 float:left;
 margin-left:35px;
}
.livros ul
{
 width:674px;
 float:left;
 margin:10px 0 0 0;
 padding:0;
 list-style:none;
}
.livros ul li
{
 display:inline-block;
 float:left;
 vertical-align:top;
 padding:30px 0 6px 36px;
}
.livros ul li a
{
 color:#333333;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.livros ul li figure
{
 transition: 0.7s ease-out;
}
.livros ul li figure:hover
{
 transform: scale(1.1);
 transition: 0.7s ease-in;
}
#page_livros .livros
{
 margin-top:30px;
 padding-bottom:15px;
}
.page
{
 
 position:absolute;
 bottom:20px;
 width:716px;
}
.page a
{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 background:#4F8D4B;
 border-radius:2px;
 padding:5px;
 margin-right:10px;
}
.meio
{
 font:20px Trebuchet MS;
 background:#356033;
 border-radius:2px;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 margin:60px 10px 0 0;
 display:inline;
 padding:5px;
}
.pilha_livros
{
 margin:70px 0 0 5px;
}
.sobre p
{
 font:30px Trebuchet MS;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 margin:50px 0 50px 8px;
}
.sobre img
{
 margin-right:8px;
}
.alignright
{
 float:right;
 margin:0 8px 10px 10px;
 border:2px solid #B6610B;
}
.alignleft
{
 float:left;
 margin:0 10px 10px 0;
 border:2px solid #B6610B;
}
.descricao_livro
{
 margin-left:10px;
}
.descricao_livro figure
{
 float:right;
 margin:23px 0 10px 10px;
}
.descricao_livro figcaption
{
 margin-left:57px;
}
.descricao_livro #download
{
 color:#FFFFFF;
 font:23px Arial;
}
.descricao_livro h3
{
 margin-left:10px;
 color:#FFFFFF;
}
.descricao_livro h1
{
 margin:30px 0 0 0;
 color:#FFFFFF;
}
.descricao_livro h2
{
 text-align:center;
}
.descricao_livro img
{
 border:3px solid #B35900;
}
/*PÁGINA BATERISTAS*/
.bateristas
{
 width:984px;
 margin:30px 0 0 8px;
}
.bateristas iframe
{
 width:300px;
 height:200px;
}
.bateristas ul
{
 display:inline-block;
 margin:0 0 0 23px;
 width:940px;
 padding:0;
 list-style:none;
}
.bateristas ul li
{
 float:left;
 padding:0 0 0 10px;
 margin:10px 0 0 0;
}
.bateristas ul li iframe
{
 border:3px solid #B35900;
}
.ordem
{
 width:100%;
 background:#FFFFFF;
 float:left;
 margin:20px 0 20px 0;
 border:6px solid #CCC;
 padding:20px 0 20px 0;
}
.ordem span
{
 font:23px Trebuchet MS;
 border-radius:2px;
 padding:5px;
 background:#4F8D4B;
 margin:-10px 0 0 5px;
 float:left;
 color:#FFFFFF;
}
#alfabeto
{
 width:984px;
 float:left;
 padding-bottom:20px;
 margin:30px 0 0 8px;
 background:#FFFFFF;
}
#alfabeto span
{
 font:23px Trebuchet MS;
 border-radius:2px;
 padding:5px;
 background:#4F8D4B;
 margin:20px 5px 0 0;
 float:left;
 color:#FFFFFF;
}
#alfabeto span a
{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#FFFFFF;
}
#alfabeto #sub
{
 margin-left:132px;
 float:left;
}

/*PÁGINA DESENHOS*/

.desenhos
{
 width:984px;
 border:5px solid #CCC;
 background:#FFFFFF;
 margin:30px 0 20px 8px;
 padding:20px 0 20px 0;
}
.desenhos ul
{
 margin:0 0 0 27px;
 display:inline-block;
 width:100%;
 padding:0;
 list-style:none;
}
.desenhos ul li
{
 vertical-align:top;
 padding:10px 0 0 5px;
 margin:0;
 float:left;
}
.desenhos ul li img
{
 border:3px solid #B35900;
 transition: 0.7s ease-out;
}
.desenhos ul li img:hover
{
 transform: scale(1.1);
 transition: 0.7s ease-in;
}

/* PÁGINA CONTATO */

.contato
{
 width:984px;
 font:23px Trebuchet MS;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 margin:30px 0 20px 8px;
 background:#FFFFFF;
 border:6px solid #CCC;
 float:left;
}
.contato form
{
 width:400px;
 margin:8px 0 10px 8px;
 background:#356033;
 padding:20px 0 40px 0;
 float:left;
}
.contato img
{
 float:left;
 margin-top:40px;
 margin-right:20px;
}
.contato input
{
 width:350px;
 background:#B35900;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 margin-left:25px;
 font:19px Trebuchet MS;
}
#redes
{
 width:525px;
 height:664px;
 background:#356033;
 float:left;
 padding:20px 0 10px 0;
 margin:8px 0 0 30px;
}
#redes p
{
 font:23px Trajan Pro;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 text-align:center;
 border-bottom:6px solid #FFFFFF;
 margin:0 0 20px 0;
 padding-bottom:10px;
}
#redes h1
{
 clear:both;
}
#redes h3
{
 clear:both;
}
#face
{
 margin-left:167px
}
.contato #aviso
{
 font:12px arial;
 margin-left:25px;
 display:none;
 font-weight:bold;
}
.contato label
{
 margin-left:25px;
}
.contato textarea
{
 width:350px;
 background:#B35900;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 margin-left:25px;
 font:19px Trebuchet MS;
}
.contato h1
{
 font:23px Trajan Pro;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 text-align:center;
 border-bottom:6px solid #FFFFFF;
 margin:0 0 20px 0;
 padding-bottom:10px;
}
.contato_btn
{
 font:23px Trebuchet MS;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 margin-left:50px;
 background:#B35900;
}

/*PÁGINA DE PESQUISA*/

.search #resultado
{
 width:984px;
 margin: 20px 0 20px 8px;
 background:#FFFFFF;
 border:6px solid #CCC;
 min-height:260px;
 padding:10px 10px 60px 10px;
}
.search #resultado:hover
{
 background:#B5D7B3;
}
.search #mensagem
{
 text-align:center;
 font:35px Tranjan Pro;
 color:#FFFFFF;
}
.search h1
{
 text-align:center;
 font:35px Tranjan Pro;
 color:#575748;
}
.link_search
{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#575748;
}
.link_search:hover
{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#575748;
}
.search #paginas
{
 width:984px;
 margin: 20px 0 20px 8px;
 background:#FFFFFF;
 border:6px solid #CCC;
 padding:20px 0 20px 5px;
}
#primeira_search a
{
 text-decoration:none;
 font:20px Trebuchet MS;
 margin-right:10px;
 border-radius:2px;
 padding:5px;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 margin-top:10px;
 background:#4F8D4B;
}
#meio_search
{
 font:20px Trebuchet MS;
 background:#356033;
 border-radius:2px;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 padding:5px;
 margin-right:10px;
}
.lados_search a
{
 text-decoration:none;
 font:20px Trebuchet MS;
 margin-right:10px;
 border-radius:2px;
 padding:5px;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 margin-top:10px;
 background:#4F8D4B;
}
#ultima_search a
{
 text-decoration:none;
 font:20px Trebuchet MS;
 margin-right:10px;
 border-radius:2px;
 padding:5px;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 margin-top:10px;
 background:#4F8D4B;
}

/* PÁGINA ENVIADO */

.enviado
{
 width:984px;
 margin:60px 0 60px 8px;
}
.enviado h1
{
 font:28px Trajan Pro;
 text-align:center;
 color:#FFFFFF;
}
.enviado h3
{
 font:26px Trajan Pro;
 text-align:center;
 color:#FFFFFF;
}

/*RODAPÉ*/

footer
{
 height:216px;
 background:#142413;
 clear:both;
}
footer p
{
 font:26px Trebuchet MS;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 margin:62px 0 0 27px;
 float:left;
}
footer img
{
 width:365px;
 margin-top:70px;
 margin-right:15px;
 float:right;
}
footer #facebook
{
 clear:both;
 float:right;
 width:30px;
 margin-right:295px;
 margin-top:-10px;
}
footer #instagram
{
 float:right;
 width:35px;
 margin-top:-12px;
}
```

mobile.css

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 854px)
{
 .container
 {
  width:96%;
 }
 header #logo
 {
  margin-left:27%;
 }
 header #livros
 {
  float:right;
  margin-right:12%;
 }
 header .menu_nav
 {
  display:inline;
  margin-left:0;
  margin-top:16px;
 }
 header .pesquisa
 {
  width:90.9%;
  margin-top:2%;
 }
 header .divisor
 {
  display:none;
 }
 header .menu
 {
  display:none;
  width:98%;
  height:273px;
 }
 header nav ul
 {
  width:100px;
 }
 header #pesquisar
 {
  width:92%;
 }
 .banner_desenhos
 {
  width:65%;
 }
 .banner_desenhos img
 {
  width:95%;
 }
 .categorias
 {
  margin-right:0;
 }
 .livros
 {
  width:65%;
  height:1450px;
  margin-top:-120px;
 }
 .livros ul
 {
  width:600px;
 }
 .livros ul li
 {
  padding:30px 35px 6px 2%;
 }
 .livros h1
 {
  width:96%;
  margin-left:2%;
 }
 .livros #grade_livros
 {
  width:96%;
  margin-left:2%;
 }
 .page
 {
  width:100%;
 }
 .categorias
 {
  margin-right:5px;
  
 }
 #alfabeto
 {
  width:98%;
 }
 #alfabeto #sub
 {
  margin-left:5%;
 }
 .bateristas
 {
  width:98%;
 }
 .bateristas ul
 {
  width:800px;
 }
 .bateristas ul li
 {
  padding:0 73px 73px 0;
 }
 .desenhos
 {
  width:98%;
 }
 .desenhos ul
 {
  margin-left:8%;
 }
 .desenhos ul li
 {
  padding:0 30px 30px 0;
 }
 .contato
 {
  width:98%;
 }
 .contato form
 {
  width:48%;
 }
 .contato input
 {
  width:85%;
 }
 .contato textarea
 {
  width:85%;
 }
 #redes
 {
  width:49%;
  margin-left:5px;
 }
 #face
 {
  margin-left:23.2%;
 }
 footer p
 {
  font-size:20px;
 }
 footer img
 {
  margin-top:60px;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px)
{
 header #logo
 {
  margin-left:20%;
 }
 header .pesquisa
 {
  width:90.5%;
 }
 .banner_desenhos
 {
  width:63%;
 }
 .banner_desenhos img
 {
  width:95%;
 }
 .livros
 {
  width:63%;
  margin-top:-150px;
 }
 .livros ul li
 {
  padding:30px 10px 6px 2%;
 }
 .page
 {
  width:100%;
 }
 #alfabeto #sub
 {
  margin-left:3%;
 }
 .bateristas ul li
 {
  padding:0 65px 65px 0;
 }
 .desenhos ul
 {
  margin-left:6%;
 }
 footer p
 {
  margin-top:70px;
 }
 footer img
 {
  margin-top:70px;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 720px)
{
 header #logo
 {
  margin-left:12%;
 }
 header #livros
 {
  margin-right:10%;
 }
 header .pesquisa
 {
  width:90.1%;
  margin-top:2.4%;
  margin-right:0.5%;
 }
 header #pesquisar
 {
  width:89%;
 }
 .banner_desenhos
 {
  width:58%;
 }
 .livros
 {
  width:58%;
  height:2050px;
  margin-top:-200px;
 }
 .livros ul
 {
  width:400px;
 }
 .livros ul li
 {
  padding:30px 35px 6px 7%;
 }
 .bateristas iframe
 {
  width:90%;
 }
 .bateristas ul li
 {
  padding:0 10px 10px 0;
 }
 .desenhos img
 {
  width:232px;
 }
 .desenhos ul
 {
  margin-left:10%;
 }
 footer p
 {
  font-size:20px;
  margin-left:29%;
  margin-top:50px;
 }
 footer img
 {
  float:left;
  margin-left:22%;
  margin-top:30px;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
{
 header #logo
 {
  margin-left:18%;
 }
 header #livros
 {
  display:none;
 }
 header .pesquisa
 {
  width:88%;
 }
 header #pesquisar
 {
  width:88%;
 }
 header .menu_nav
 {
  margin-top:13px;
 }
 .banner_desenhos
 {
  width:50%;
 }
 .livros ul
 {
  width:275px;
 }
 .livros
 {
  margin-top:-270px;
  margin-right:0
  height:1750px;
 }
 .livros figure
 {
  width:132px;
 }
 .livros img
 {
  width:80%;
 }
 .livros h1
 {
  font-size:20px;
 }
 .livros figcaption
 {
  font-size:18px;
 }
 .livros
 {
  width:50%;
 }
 .livros ul li
 {
  padding:30px 4px 6px 0.5%;
 }
 .bateristas ul
 {
  width:450px;
  margin-left:15%;
 }
 .bateristas iframe
 {
  width:400px;
  height:250px;
 }
 .desenhos ul
 {
  margin-left:9%;
 }
 .desenhos img
 {
  width:200px;
 }
 .contato input
 {
  width:90%;
 }
 .contato textarea
 {
  width:90%;
 }
 .contato form
 {
  width:98%;
 }
 .descricao_livro figcaption
 {
  margin-right:11px;
 }
 .descricao_livro figure
 {
  width:200px;
 }
 .descricao_livro img
 {
  width:70%;
 }
 #redes
 {
  width:98%;
  height:220px;
 }
 #face
 {
  margin-left:32%;
 }
 footer p
 {
  margin-left:25%;
 }
 footer img
 {
  margin-left:16%;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px)
{
 header #logo
 {
  margin-left:4%;
 }
 header .pesquisa
 {
  width:85%;
 }
 header #pesquisar
 {
  width:84%;
 }
 header .menu_nav
 {
  margin-top:9px;
 }
 .banner_desenhos
 {
  width:35%;
 }
 .livros ul
 {
  width:170px;
  margin-left:5%;
 }
 .livros
 {
  width:35%;
 }
 .livros h1
 {
  padding-left:5px;
  font-size:15px;
 }
 .sobre img
 {
  display:none;
 }
}
```

header.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css"/>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
 <script src="js/cycle2.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.2/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.2/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validacao.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/show_menu.js"></script>
<?php
 $conexao = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "meusite");
 
 include("limita_palavras.php");
 
 if (empty($_SESSION)) session_start();
 if (empty($_SESSION['UsuarioID']))
 {
  session_destroy();
 }
 
 $verificar_manu = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT status FROM manutencao WHERE status = 'ativo'")or die(mysqli_query($conexao));
 if(mysqli_num_rows($verificar_manu) >= 1 && empty($_SESSION['UsuarioID']))
 {
  echo "<h1>Site em manutenção...</h1>";
  exit;
 }
 
 if(isset($_GET['topicos']))
 {
  $temp = explode('/',$_GET['topicos']);
  $pgatual = strtolower(end($temp));
 }
 else
 {
  $pgatual = "";
 }
?>
<title>BibliotecaDC | <?=$pgatual;?></title>
</head>
<body>
<header class="container">
 <a href="index.php?topicos=nav/home"><img id="logo" width="394" src="images/logo.png"/></a>
 <img id="livros" width="115" src="images/livros.png"/>

 <div class="pesquisa">
  <form name="form" action="index.php?topicos=nav/search" method="post">
   <input id="lupa" type="image" src="images/lupa.png"/> 
   <input name="pesquisa" type="text" id="pesquisar"/>
  </form>
 </div>
 <div class="menu_nav">
  <div class="grade"></div>
  <div class="grade"></div>
  <div class="grade"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
 <nav class="menu">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="index.php?topicos=nav/sobre">Sobre</a></li><div class="divisor"></div>
   <li><span><a href="index.php?topicos=nav/livros">Livros</a></span></li><div class="divisor"></div>
   <li><span><a href="index.php?topicos=nav/bateristas">Bateristas</a></span></li><div class="divisor"></div>
   <li><span><a href="index.php?topicos=nav/desenhos">Desenhos</a></span></li><div class="divisor"></div>
   <li id="final_list"><span><a href="index.php?topicos=nav/contato">Contato</a></span></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
```

index.php

```
<?php include"header.php";?>
<?php
if(empty($_GET['topicos']))
{
    include("nav/home.php");
}
elseif(substr($_GET['topicos'], 0,4)=='http' or 
substr($_GET['topicos'],0,1)=='/' or substr($_GET['topicos'],0,1)=='.')
{
    echo"<font face=Arial size=11px><br>A Página Não Existe</font>";
}
else
{
    include($_GET['topicos'].".php");
}
?>
<?php include"footer.php";?>
```

footer.php

```html
<footer class="container">
 <p>&copy: 2018 - DC Desenvolvimento<br/> &nbsp;&nbsp;Todos os direitos reservados</p>
 <img src="images/DCDesenvolvimento.png"/>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bom dia.
Tem / como tem definida a meta tag viewport?

Comment: tenha definido no viewport o tamanho da proporção como device width assim
`<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />`

Comment: Como está a estrutura do seu CSS? Vc sabe que as regras @media devem ser as últimas linhas do seu código né? Tipo primeiro vem todo seu CSS normal, depois lá no final que vc faz os  "@media screen and (max-width: 720px)" etc... O seu está assim?

Comment: Coloquei essa viewport toda aí, não adiantou, e eu to usando os media querys num arquivo separado do meu CSS normal, acho que o problema não deve ser isso certo @hugocsl?

Comment: Usar em um arquivo separado não é problema. MAS... o que vc tem que ter atenção é que no `<head>` do site primeiro deve vir a indexação do .CSS padrão, depois dele na linha de baixo vc indexa o .CSS com as classes responsivas... Ex: `<link href="padrao.css" rel="stylesheet">` e na linha de baixo depois desse .css `<link href="responsivo.css" rel="stylesheet"> ` o seu está dessa forma??

Comment: Sim, está assim mesmo.

Comment: Eu vou acrescentar informações pra vcs me ajudarem melhor.

Comment: Cara to achando que o seu problema é com a indexação do código na página, confere se os arquivos estão nas pastas corretas, e se vc está colocando o caminho completo do arquivo .css... por ex: `href="../css/padrao.css"` Vc pode Ir no DevTools do Chrome e ir na Aba Network, da um F5 e confere se todos os arquivos .css foram carregados!

Comment: como forma de testar se existe algum erro na declaração das media queries podes verficar se o ambiente de teste tem as condiçoes necessárias com o **window.matchMedia**?
[exemplo: `window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 720px)").matches]`

Comment: Pode explicar melhor?

Comment: em que ambiente estas a testar as media queries?
se utilizares as devTools do Chrome por exemplo, e tiveres na resolução que pretendes testar, podes executar o comando colocado anteriormente (_window.matchMedia_) com a media query que tens no teu css, se a função retornar true é porque apesar de a media query estar correcta pode haver outra a sobrepor-se ou o teu codigo nao esta mesmo a chegar à media query
se der false tens algo que nao está a bater certo com a media query e por isso não vês resultados

Comment: To testando no Chrome, utilizando o que vc falou, parece que o layout se altera, quando eu tiro o layout volta ao normal. O site já está hospedado se vc quer saber, é esse o ambiente que queria saber?

Comment: @David o que perguntava era precisamente se estavas a utilizar as devtools num desktop, simulando as resoluções de ecra através das tools.
Que tipo de propriedades tens a falhar?
As queries estao a responder segundo o codigo que colocaste, mas 
tem atenção se nas media queries estás a alterar "tudo" para todas as resoluçoes, pois da forma como estao, a sobrepor-se, podes estar a puxar codigo de mais de uma resolução e por isso nao te está a bater certo. ex: se tens width=720, as queries de max-width: 800px e max-width: 720px estão a actuar, se não houver sobreposiçao correcta, falha.

Comment: @Ana Teixeira Tem outra forma de fazer?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85489/discussion-between-ana-teixeira-and-david-cesar).

Answer (score 0):

experimenta esta linha que foi ana teixeira estava a dizer .

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Senão experimenta este código em css a ver se corrige a formatação.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Infelizmente não resolveu.

Comment: pode passar o css e o html para poder testar

Comment: Como mando? É muito código.

Comment: tens uma opção que quando fazer adicionar outra resposta (botão azul por baixo) tens la um icone ( < >) e só clicares nele diz la html e no lado css e só pores la e fazeres adicionar a pergunta

Comment: adicionei, testa lá.

Comment: experimenta mudar os 1000px para 100% isto se for para ecran inteiro a ver se da para resolver o problema tudo o que e width muda para % quando se trata de containers ou layouts em nivel the heights da valores de vh sendo 100 vh o full screen tens aqui uma boa explicação de como funciona https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/

Comment: Na hora de adaptar pra mobile eu coloquei porcentagens nas larguras.